Is power of a lens in a medium $1/f$ or $n/f$?
I have read the formula that power of a lens is $1/f$. So I assumed that this formula is always valid. If we put the lens in a medium we should just calculate the new focal length in the medium and apply the formula. But recently I have been told by a colleague that it should be $n/f$ where $n$ is the focal length of surroundings. The new formula is also consistent with power of a single refractive surface that is (n2-n1)/r and not 1/f for the surface. But I have not found any text supporting this.

I hope you have heard about the Lensmaker's equation. This can be easily derived using basic laws of refraction.
$$\frac{1}{f} = (n_{21}-1)\left( {1\over R_1} - {1\over R_2} \right)$$
For a thin lens(we neglect its thickness)
Here,

$f$ is the focal length(with sign convention)
$n_{21}$ is the refractive index of the lens with respect to the medium surrounding it($n_{lens}$/$n_{medium}$)
$R_1$ and $R_2$ are the radii of curvature of the lens(with sign convention)

Since we know that $\frac{1}{f}$ is the power of a lens, when $f$ is in meter, we can use this relation to get its power in any medium. Note that if we use $n$/$f$, we will get an extra term of $n$ in this equation.
To sum up, the focal length, and hence the power of a lens depends on the medium in which it is placed in a not so direct manner(as in $n$/$f$) but rather the relation is given by the above equation.
